# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secondpage.forms'

Tags: python, django

[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from secondpage.forms import NewUserForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'secondpage/index.html')

def users(request):

    form = NewUserForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

        else:
            print("Error form invalid")

    return render(request,'secondpage/users.html',{'form':form})
```

I have `__init__.py` file in the apps directory and I am in the correct path. I also have the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` but the terminal is throwing the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You named the file `form.py`, not `forms.py`.

Comment: Your file is called form.py instead of forms.py

Comment: Wow... what a silly mistake. Thank you